# Python. Библиотека Dispy. Как запустить большее количество задач на кластере, чем количество процессоров?

Tags: python, распараллеливание, кластер

Пишу программу на языке Python для распределения вычислений на несколько ПК (пытаюсь ускорить обработку данных). Выбрал библиотеку **Dispy**.
Вышло запустить тестовую программу на двух ПК (см. ниже).

**Проблема:**
При переходе на практическую задачу с предварительной обработкой текстовых данных, программа не может нагрузить ядра компьютеров на 100% (только около 20%). Проблема связана с тем, что функция `rtask()` запускает не более 24 задач, по 12 задач на ПК (соответствует количеству виртуальных ядер).

Пытался использовать функцию `io_rtask()` (без ограничения на количество задач), но возникла другая проблема. При использовании функции `io_rtask()` выбирается только один случайный сервер. То есть теперь можно запустить больше задач на ПК (сервере), но все задачи попадают на 1 ПК (сервер). При этом сервер выбирается случайно, второй игнорируется.

**Вопрос:** Как запустить заданное количество задач не зависимо от количества ядер и на всех ПК?
Например, как запустить 50 задач на 24 ядрах, чтобы они считали одновременно и не стояли в очереди вычислений.

**Пример программы** (исходная программа большая, поэтому обработку текстов заменил на простой цикл с вычислениями):

```
# Run 'dispycosnode.py' program to start processes to execute computations sent
# by this client, along with this program.

# Distributed computing example where this client sends computation ('compute'
# function) to remote dispycos servers to run as remote tasks and obtain
# results. At any time at most one computation task is scheduled at a process,
# as the computation is supposed to be CPU heavy (although in this example they
# are not).


# this generator function is sent to remote dispycos servers to run tasks there
# тестовая функция с вычислениями на ПК
def compute(i, task=None):
    yield 0 # пока не разобрался как избавиться от строки, нужна, чтобы работало
    import numpy as np
    import time
    for ii in range(50000):
        a = np.random.random([100 * 100])
        b = np.random.random([100 * 100])
        c = a*b
    return (i, 0, c[:10])



# -- code below is executed locally --

# client (local) task submits tasks
def client_proc(njobs, task=None):
    # schedule client with the scheduler; scheduler accepts one client
    # at a time, so if scheduler is shared, the client is queued until it
    # is done with already scheduled clients
    if (yield client.schedule()):
        raise Exception('Could not schedule client')

    # schedule tasks on dispycos servers
    rtasks = []
    for i in range(njobs):
        # computation is supposed to be CPU bound so 'rtask' is used so at most
        # one computations runs at a server at any time; for mostly idle
        # computations, 'io_rtask' may be used to run more than one task at a
        # server at the same time.
        
        # ---
        # ВОЗМОЖНОЕ МЕСТО ОШИБКИ
        #rtask = yield client.rtask(compute, i) # распределяет задачи на все ПК, но не более чем количество ядер
        rtask = yield client.io_rtask(compute, i) # распределяет все задачи независимо от количества ядер, но почему-то на случайный сервер (остальные игнорирует)
        # ---
        
        if isinstance(rtask, pycos.Task):
            rtasks.append(rtask)
        else:
            print('  ** rtask failed for %s' % i)
    
    # wait for results
    for rtask in rtasks:
        result = yield rtask()
        if isinstance(result, tuple) and len(result) == 3:
            print('  +++  result for %d from %s: %s' % result)
        elif isinstance(result, pycos.MonitorStatus):
            print('    ** rtask %s failed: %s with %s' % (rtask, result.type, result.value))
        else:
            print('    ** rtask %s failed' % rtask)

    # close client
    yield client.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys, random
    import pycos
    import pycos.netpycos
    from pycos.dispycos import *

    # package client fragments
    nodes = ['109.123.171.38', '109.123.171.39'] # '109.123.171.38', '109.123.171.39'
    client = Client([compute], nodes=nodes)
    # run 20 jobs
    pycos.Task(client_proc, 20)
```